# Indexing of NDEigensystem Result on a Cluster

Tags: numerics, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, high-performance-clusters

I am trying to run on a cluster (where the version 11 of Mathematica is available) a code involving the following calculation:

```
    1). {Values, States} = NDEigensystem[{-D[u[r], {r, 2}] + V[r] u[r], u[R] == 0}, u[r], {r,0,R}, 10];
```

where I omitted the method specifications.

When I run it on my laptop (where I use the version 12.2), I have no problem accessing the different eigenstates with `Evaluate[States][[i]]` or, equivalently, with `Evaluate[States[[i]]]`, but on the cluster I get an error saying that the left and righthand side of equation 1) have a different shape.

I then tried to name the lefthand side of 1) simply as `Solution` and to access the eigenvalues with `Evaluate[Solution][[1,i]]` and `Evaluate[Solution][[2,i]]` (or `Evaluate[Solution[[1,i]]]` and `Evaluate[Solution[[2,i]]]`) respectively. Again, both work on my laptop but neither of them work on the cluster. In this case, the error says that part 2 (or more) of `u[r]` does not exist.

Moreover, even the calculation of the first eigenstate seems to be different.

Is there something I am not considering about the difference between the two versions of Mathematica? Or is there any difference between running a code locally or on a cluster?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I do not believe that versions 11 vs 12 would matter here.